# debian cannot install kernel source

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, source

I want to use debian linux for my laptop again. So I took my old debian 6.0 cds and installed it.
From the last time I know, that I have to build the driver for my Atheros AR8151 Gigabit Ethernet Controller.
It seems that this time I installed less base packets.
I had to install make and gcc (apt-get install build-essential).
Now I want to build the driver.
When I go to the src folder and type make install, I read

```
Linux kernel source not found
```

So I googled, found some answers and typed

```
apt-get install kernel-source-2.6.32-5-amd64
```

with the following message

```
paket could not be found
```

The directory `/usr/src` is empty.

Answer (score 3):

It is unclear to me where you got that `apt-get install` line from, as googling does not give any direct hits. 
 The output message you got was probably something more like:

```
 Unable to locate package kernel-source-2.6.32-5-amd64
```

(it is also strange that the **source** would be amd64 specific)

You should try with the correct package name for the kernel sources:

```
apt-get install linux-source-2.6.32
```

more info on that [here](http://packages.debian.org/de/squeeze/linux-source-2.6.32)